# Prevent message when writing buffer

Tags: neovim, save

Whenever I write a file in Neovim, I get a message like this:

```
"config/nvim/lua/config/keymaps.lua" 55L, 2256B
```

Sometimes, this can cause a `press ENTER or type command to continue` message to pop up, which is annoying.

Is there any way to suppress the file write message?

I'd still like to see other messages, such as warnings that I'm overwriting something.

Answer (score 1):

I you prefix the command with `silent` you will not get the message.

e.g.:

```
:silent w
```

You can go event further with `silent!`

e.g.:

```
:silent! w
```

Remark: The `press ENTER or type command to continue` make me believe that some plugin are involved that trigger error messages that need confirmation. The `silent!` trick will work but it would be good to understand why the plugin complains (maybe more information using the `:messages` command to get more information about the complains).